# minecraft forge modding mods folder

Tags: eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I tried to test a Minecraft Mod im developing right now and this error popped up in the console:

```
[15:31:05] [main/INFO] [FML]: Searching E:\MinecraftForgeMods\forge-1.12.2-14.23.4.2705-mdk\run\.\mods for mods
[15:31:05] [main/ERROR] [FML]: Unable to construct net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod container
```

In theory there shouldn't be a folder between 'run' and 'mods'. I tried creating such a folder, but that doesn't work of course, and searched for while but found nothing to this problem.

So does anyone have an idea how to get the right searching path?

Answer (score 1):

As per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249039/what-means-the-dots-on-a-path

`E:\MinecraftForgeMods\forge-1.12.2-14.23.4.2705-mdk\run\.\mods`

will resolve to `E:\MinecraftForgeMods\forge-1.12.2-14.23.4.2705-mdk\run\mods`

`.` represents the current directory, when it's mid-way through a path, it doesn't do anything.

The reason it's getting displayed, is the path that is being output isn't the resolved/absolute path, but the relative/dynamic path that has been built from multiple pieces.

> this error popped up

The first line isn't an Error! It's an INFO, there is no reason to worry, this is normal.

> Unable to construct net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod container

This is a problem, but unless there were lines before this it's hard if not impossible to tell what's going wrong.

If you have other mods in your mods directory, try removing them.

If this has only started happening after you started making your mod, Then it's likely something in your mod.

Usually there is a stack trace immediately after that, this one shows an issue in

> *Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The modid CraftingTableIV is not the same as it's lowercase version. Lowercasing will be enforced in 1.11
>          at

```
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
   at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.ModContainerFactory.build(ModContainerFactory.java:86) [ModContainerFactory.class:?]
   at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.discovery.JarDiscoverer.discover(JarDiscoverer.java:87) [JarDiscoverer.class:?]
   at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.discovery.ContainerType.findMods(ContainerType.java:49) [ContainerType.class:?]
   at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.discovery.ModCandidate.explore(ModCandidate.java:78) [ModCandidate.class:?]
   at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.discovery.ModDiscoverer.identifyMods(ModDiscoverer.java:141) [ModDiscoverer.class:?]
   at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.identifyMods(Loader.java:382) [Loader.class:?]
   at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:522) [Loader.class:?]
   at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:225) [FMLClientHandler.class:?]
   at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:438) [beq.class:?]
   at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:350) [beq.class:?]
   at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124) [Main.class:?]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
   at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
   at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The modid CraftingTableIV is not the same as it's lowercase version. Lowercasing will be enforced in 1.11
   at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.sanityCheckModId(FMLModContainer.java:144) ~[FMLModContainer.class:?]
   at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.<init>(FMLModContainer.java:126) ~[FMLModContainer.class:?]
   ... 21 more
```